# Flare Dependency graph not being displayed when project migrated from Flex3 to Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flare

I have a project in Flex 3 which uses Flare to create and display a Dependency graph.i have recently migrated my project from Flex 3 to Flex 4 and found that the graph is not being displayed.Flex 4 needs Flash Player 10 and i am not sure if Flare has support for the same.Could be because of this?
Shashank

Comment: share your exceptions output. Did you setup compiler for flex 3 extending from flex 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can make from flare external swf component and embed it to your main application, and communicate with it via core interface.

But I think it will be better to deal with flex 4 from flare, because it supports it! So if you'll able to share the piece of your code, we might help you.

Thank you!